# Django : Booking complex Slot booking system

Tags: python, django, django-models, timeslots

I have a simple slot booking system in my current project. I will be configuring 3 times per day and all the AVAILABLE slots should be displayed in the UI where a user can select the time slot like:

Date1: radio button Time1 radio button Time2 radio button Time3

Date2 radio button Time1 radio button Time2 radio button Time3

Date3 radio button Time1 radio button Time2 radio button Time3

Or something like below where in the date is selected and the ONLY available time slots are available.

Date1:
   Time1
   Time2
   Time3
Date2
   Time1
   Time2
   Time3
.....so on

There should be a radio button against each and every time slot.

P.S : I am planning to show some time slots to free users and more slots to paid users.

Here is the model I have written

```
class TimeSlot(models.Model):
    plan_code_choices=(
                    ('F','Free'),
                    ('S','Standard'),
                    ('A','Advanced'),
                    ('P','Premium')
        )
    plan_code = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=plan_code_choices,default=plan_code_choices[0][0])
    date_slot = models.DateField()
    # slot_id =models.IntegerField(choices=slot_id_choices)
    time1=models.TimeField()
    time1_isbooked = models.BooleanField(default=False,blank=True)
    time2=models.TimeField()
    time2_isbooked = models.BooleanField(default=False,blank=True)
    time3=models.TimeField()
    time3_isbooked = models.BooleanField(default=False,blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}-{1}-{2}".format(self.plan_code,self.time1,self.time2)
```

I am clueless as in how to project it in my view and make it actionable in HTML.

Comment: Check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial03/